# Database relation design - Relating two tables twice in different tables

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, database-design

I have the following tables:

```
Post
Id int

User
Id int
```

Then I have the table

```
Favorite
PostId int
UserId int
```

and the table

```
Vote
PostId int
UserId int
IsUpVote bit
IsDownVote bit
LastActivity datetime2
```

the problem is that if I merged both Favorite and Vote into a single table, then I'd have something like

```
UserPost
PostId int
UserId int
IsFavorited bit
IsUpVoted bit
IsDownVoted bit
LastActivity datetime2
```

`IsDownVote` couldn't be computed anymore (since now, I can't use a "doesn't exist: didn't vote; didn't vote up: voted down" pattern anymore) and `LastActivity` will only reflect the last time the vote has changed (either up, down, or removed). So I'd maybe have to change that field's name or it's functionality. or even both..

So the question is basically, how wrong is having two tables relating Tables A and B `(Post,User)` in this case, which are indexed by the same primary key `(PostId,UserId)` in this case, but which are intended for different uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favourites and Votes seem to be two different things, so IMHO you will be better off keeping them as separate tables. As you mentioned, you would lose functionality if you merged them, and I don't see any clear benefit to merge them. Stick with what you've got unless you can provide an *awesome* justification for the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong at all.

I am not saying that the DDL provided shows correctly Normalised tables, but they are somewhat Normalised.  As you have identified yourself, the two tables have different purposes, they have different meaning, so technically (theoretically, academically, and in practice [code] ), they are correct.

- "related to the same parents" is not a criterion (there are many instances where there are many tables related to the same parents, and which are correct)
- therefore such tables will "have the same PKs and FKs", so that is not a criterion either.

Only someone with no real concept of Normalisation, and no concept of the causes of negative performance, will suggest that "just because they have the same parents (and therefore the same pair of keys/indices)", they should be merged.

Vote and Favourite are two different Things, Entities, records of Action taken.  Two tables is correct.

Distinction: The real reason IsDownVoted cannot be compared anymore is that it does not apply to Favourite.  You have used an Indicator (bit) to identify that (although badly named); which is really a substitute for a Null column.  Nulls are not good for performance, and it is a Good Thing that you have Indicators to identify the absence of data, and therefore avoided Nulls, but that is separate to breaking a Normalised design by mereging them.

The merged table will perform slower on all accesses.  When you SELECT Votes from it, you have to exclude Favourites, and vice versa, but it will be doing I/O for both, because they are located together (PostId, UserId).  SO the server is forever reading twice as many rows, using twice as much cache; etc.  Then you will "add speed" by *adding* an index for (PostId, UserId, IsFavourited), making it even slower for Inserts and Deletes (while "speeding up" Selects). Messes get compounded, guaranteed; best to not have any mess in the first place.

When the database grows, you can independently add columns to either one of Vote and Favourite, without affecting the other.  In a merged table, it will introduce complications.

You accept Answers too quickly.

Answer (score -1):

While I won't say what you should do table wise if you use int instead of bit and use values like 0 1 and -1 to do calculations / comparisons, this way you could compute the values you want in a relatively simple way.

Talking relational databases you should almost always aim for 3'rd normal form regarding your tables - Try looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Cheers!

Comment: -1 What exactly is the difficulty is using bit values to do calculations/comparisons (that you can do with ints) ?!?  is there some reason you like storing bit values in 4 bytes instead of 1 bit ?

Comment: They guy was having trouble using the bit values for some calculations hence the suggestion. I have myself in my day implemented a binary standard for encoding ECG for my main thesis so I do not have any particular problems with this. My suggestion was merely to allow the guy to jump over where the fence was the lowest and solve his immediate problem all while asking him to read up on 3'rd normal form to allow his database to fall into the correct normal form, sometimes the best solution is a quick fix and then to refine and rethink your solution.

Comment: Right.  And then, after doing all that, change the database and the app code.  That would be a horrendous labour.  What about modelling the database correctly in the first place, and avoiding all that re-work.

Comment: @Performance DBA - I absolutely agree with you on modeling the database correctly in the first place, which is why I pointed the to the article, however sometimes you don't have the luxury of changing a DB's design and thus have to hack around a flawed design hence the suggestion, but I do not think this is the right place to discuss the matter further as Nico has chosen his path. I'd like to suggest that, if you are looking for discussion of any kind that you get in touch with Nico and discuss his choices and his work here, after all it is his question that deserves to be in focus.

Comment: True. If you read the guidelines you will find that we are encouraged to correct incorrect answers, so that when people (other than Nico) search SO, they get accurate, improved info.